# In the place of the button over the thing? What is it called?

Tags: java, user-interface

I just would like a regular JButton, like the following:

```
JButton buttonWCRoss = new JButton("Button out");
```

But with an image over the button and the text "Imaged Button". How do I go about doing so?

Thank you

Comment: Would disabling the button be acceptable? I have a feeling that the answer you're going to get is a lot more complicated than you will want it to be.

Answer (score 3):

I would extend JBUtton and override its paintComponent method, drawing in your cross:

```
  JButton button = new JButton("Cross Out Button") {
     @Override
     protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
              RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 150));
        g2.setStroke(CROSS_STROKE);
        int x1 = 4;
        int y1 = x1;
        int x2 = getWidth() - x1;
        int y2 = getHeight() - y1;

        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g2.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y1);
     }
  };
```

You may wish to use a semi-opaque color (as I've done above) so that the text shows through. Don't forget to set RenderingHints to get rid of jaggies.

CROSS_STROKE is a constant that I declared in my test program, a BasicStroke object:

```
   protected static final Stroke CROSS_STROKE = new BasicStroke(5, 
                   BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER);
```

Comment: would there be a way of class extending JButton and go about doing so that way? If so could you show if you don't mind? Cause I learned that method and would like to apply it

Comment: Well, that's what he did. He created an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which means he extended `JButton` but didn't give the new class a name (probably because it just was an example). For a full (non-anonymous) class see my answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels What is CROSS_STROKE supposed to be? How should it be declared?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Got it! I understand now. But if I wanted it to create it as non-anonymous class, how would I do so? Would I just do public class CrossButton extends JButton {//Put the override//} but where does do I include the "Cross Out Button" portion? Could you show if you don't mind?

Answer (score 2):

You could extend `JButton`:

```
public class CrossButton extends JButton {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(!isEnabled()) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawLine(0, getHeight(), getWidth(), 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use `setEnabled(boolean)` to draw the cross. I assume you want to cross out disabled buttons.

<s>Untested but should work.</s> Tested and works.

Comment: I tested it but only shows a blank button. How do I put text in it, ""Crossed Out Button"". In my Driver class, did this: JPanel jp = new JPanel();
  CrossButton cb = new CrossButton();
   
  jp.add(cb);
  add(jp);
  setVisible(true);

Comment: The same way as with `JButton`: `cp.setText("Crossed Out Button")`.

Comment: Do you mean cb in this case?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was half asleep when I wrote that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components With the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html). With this class you can do any kind of custom painting overtop of the component without extending the component.

Comment: Yes, this is probably the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

There is a .setText("") method that you can use to change the text on top of the button, if that's what you're asking for. In addition there is .setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.Plain, 40)) as an example, to change the font inside the button.